# Understanding SHA-256 Hashing

Tags: java, sha256

I am using Sha-256 hashing in my Java program which is working as per behavior.

I am actually a bit confused in the function I have used for SHA-256.

Following is the code of the function:

```
// Function for generating to Hash of the file content..
    public static String generateHash( String fileContent ) 
     {
        String hashtext = EMPTY_STRING;

        try {

            // SHA - 256 Message Digest..
            MessageDigest shaDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-256" );

            // digest() method is called 
            // to calculate message digest of the input string 
            // returned as array of byte 
            byte[] messageDigest = shaDigest.digest( fileContent.getBytes() ); 

            // Convert byte array into signum representation 
            BigInteger no = new BigInteger( 1, messageDigest ); 

            // Convert message digest into hex value 
            hashtext = no.toString( 16 ); 

            // Add preceding 0s to make it 32 bit 
            while ( hashtext.length() < 32 ) { 
                hashtext = "0" + hashtext; 
            }

        }
        catch ( Exception hashingException ) {

            System.out.println( "Exception in Hashing of Content = " + hashingException );

        }
         // return the HashText 
         return hashtext; 
     }
```

Now, here I am confused in three statements; as I am unaware of what is their actual purpose since I have surfed them on the internet but didnt get any explanatory stuff. Can some one elaborate these three steps to me?

**STATEMENT 1**

```
BigInteger no = new BigInteger( 1, messageDigest );
```

**STATEMENT 2**

```
 hashtext = no.toString( 16 );
```

**STATEMENT 3**

```
while ( hashtext.length() < 32 ) { 
    hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger no = new BigInteger( 1, messageDigest );
```

Covert the bytes to a Positive Sign-Magnitude representation. Read [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20byte[])) for more info.

```
hashtext = no.toString( 16 );
```

Convert the `BigInteger` number to a Base 16 (Hex Decimal) String

```
while ( hashtext.length() < 32 ) { 
    hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
}
```

Prepend `0` until the hashtext has the size of 32.

Comment: But the length in SHA-256 shall be 64 characters right? Then why it is limiting it to 32?

Comment: SHA-256 has 8 bits * 32 = 256 bits initial state size.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: **The hash is the hex representation . Firstly we converted our Message to byte endians, afterwards it was changed from signed magnitude to Big Integer to remove negative signs, then we converted it to hex representation; now the while loop checks if it has less than 32 bytes ( half a byte make 1 hex value means 32 bytes will make 64 characters of SHA-256 ) then append zeros to make it 32 bytes and print hash!**

Comment: If the length of the hash is 256 bit, represented as a hashtext string of 64 hex digits, it is pretty obvious where to fix it. Change the 32 into 64, and you're done. Don't forget to create a test case producing a hash that starts with a "0".